# Phone validation with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

so i have been working on this for a while with continuous research and tutorials and i cant seem to find what i'm doing wrong.

i have a button which looks like this

button id="create_account"

please do ignore that its missing a class and such,its all there but Stack Overflow being tricky with me, this isnt where i'm stuck.

once the button is clicked, it then runs a java script code being this

```
$(document).on("click", "#create_account", function(evt)
{
    /* this code here is not mine, found it in an online tutorial and the jsfiddle of it works, so i know this isnt the problem */
    function phonenumber(inputtxt)
    {
      var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
      if(inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))
      {
          return true;
      }
      else
      {
         alert("Not a valid Phone Number");
         return false;
      }
    }
```

});

I kind of know why this isnt working, reason being is that i'm not calling for that specific function to run, but i do know that its hitting the onclick aspect of it after some tests.

what i'm trying to do is Validate the phone number to be 10 digits (for now) i have the input type as text and id as input_phone, i will be modifying that modification for more than just 10 numbers later but i'm stuck at getting this function executed and that alert popping.

Thank you in advance for any tips/help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're **defining** a function inside the click event, not **calling** it. You can move the function body outside of the event callback, and simply just call the function from inside.

Something like this (I'm also ignoring missing variables etc, just showing you the approach):

```
$(document).on("click", "#create_account", function(evt)
{
    phonenumber($('#create_account').val()); // or whatever the input value is
})

function phonenumber(inputtxt)
{
  var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
  if(inputtxt.value.match(phoneno))
  {
      return true;
  }
  else
  {
     alert("Not a valid Phone Number");
     return false;
  }
}
```

---

```js
$(document).on("click", "#create_account", function(evt) {
  console.log(phonenumber($('#in').val()) ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid');
})


function phonenumber(inputtxt) {

  var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
  if (inputtxt.match(phoneno)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Not a valid Phone Number");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="in" />
<button id="create_account">Create Account</button>
```

---

### Plain JS Version

```js
document.getElementById('create_account').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  console.log(phonenumber(document.getElementById('in').value) ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid');
})


function phonenumber(inputtxt) {

  var phoneno = /^\d{10}$/;
  if (inputtxt.match(phoneno)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("Not a valid Phone Number");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="in" />
<button id="create_account">Create Account</button>
```

Comment: as in call the function from inside the event callback ?

Comment: Exactly! If you want something to happen on the click, you need to do an action, not define an action.

Comment: Read my comment in that line, @RobG. I have no idea where the input value is coming from, so I just grabbed the first thing I could find (obviously it refers to an input element, and not even its value). And if it was up to me, I'd ban jQuery completely (but I never said that) :X

Comment: hahah please dont ban jQuery just yet !! anyway, the value is coming from an input text field, the type is text, @RobG, i have tried this approach but it hasnt worked, i'm guessing its the .val ?

edit:
okay so i dont think .val is the problem, once i call for the function, i dont think its coming back to the event listener, as farther Alerts i have stopped popping up as well

Comment: Hey no problem, I'm glad I could help! :)

Comment: @Shomz—I realise now that the listener is on the button, not the element so *this.value* will get the button's value (i.e. *undefined*), not the input's.

Comment: @RobG, yeah, although in the OP's code we can only assume where it is - that's why I rewrote that function a bit so it accepts the string parameter... more generic and less confusing to new devs.